# Mysql CAST(CONCAT_WS trying to get correct syntax

Tags: mysql

This works

```
SELECT EntryId FROM 2_1_journal 
WHERE CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) = ?
```

But want before `WHERE` to define "virtual" column name for date with column name for example `RecordDate`.

Tried

```
SELECT EntryId FROM 2_1_journal 
CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate 
WHERE RecordDate = ?


SELECT EntryId FROM 2_1_journal 
CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) AS RecordDate 
WHERE RecordDate = ?


SELECT EntryId FROM 2_1_journal 
CAST((CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) AS RecordDate) 
WHERE RecordDate = ?
```

In all cases get error `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CAST`.

Please advice what is correct synatax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html:

> *“It is not permissible to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed. See Section C.5.5.4, [Problems with Column Aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html).”*

If you want to *select* the result of an operation in the WHERE clause as a column value as well, then you will have to write that operation two times – once in the WHERE clause, without an alias, and in the column list after SELECT as well.